Reading directory in lftp - Changed Date is not unambiguously
I am using lftp to read from an ftp server - When I read the current directory with ls -R, in the result for the date is not always the same:
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1213487 Mar 10  2024 A2024031004000171.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1147352 Apr 21  2024 A2024042104000172.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1146095 May 12  2024 A2024051204000173.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1148535 Jun  9 04:29 A2024060904000174.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1155371 Jul 14 04:27 A2024071404000175.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1150829 Aug 11 04:23 A2024081104000176.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1151742 Sep  8 05:09 A2024090804000177.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1154313 Oct 13 04:24 A2024101304000178.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1153442 Nov 10 04:25 A2024111004000179.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1203416 Jan 14  2024 A2024011404000169.zip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 30020    30021     1214387 Feb 11  2024 A2024021104000170.zip

Sometimes it states the hour in 8th position - sometimes the year. Does anybody know why this is happening? I need to check wether or not a file was changed, and also I need the specific date - So I need both, time and year.

I don’t know about lftp but I assume this is related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/237531/116858

Yes - That's probaby it - Thank you!


By default, file timestamps are listed in abbreviated form, using a
date like ‘Mar 30 2002’ for non-recent timestamps, and a
date-without-year and time like ‘Mar 30 23:45’ for recent timestamps.
This format can change depending on the current locale as detailed
below.
A timestamp is considered to be recent if it is less than six months
old, and is not dated in the future. If a timestamp dated today is not
listed in recent form, the timestamp is in the future, which means you
probably have clock skew problems which may break programs like make
that rely on file timestamps.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Formatting-file-timestamps
